# Favicon not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, favicon

The favicon that I am trying to use for a site is showing up on the Firefox tabs, but not on the Chrome tabs.

Comment: This question is unanswerable without any sort of context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Favicon not showing up in Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375592/favicon-not-showing-up-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are some problem with the chrome while you work on a local machine.
Try uploading your webpages to any web hosting site and there with `http://` this will work fine with every browser.

IE may also not work for this on local machine. Try it in Firefox of safari

Copy the code, this will surely work:

```
<head> <link rel = "shortcut icon" href=".\favicon.ico"> </head>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16375622/1581725

Here again if someone first see this question:

1) Clear your chache. http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95582 And test another browser, lets say safari. How did you import the favicon?

2) How you should add it:

Normal favicon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

PNG/GIF favicon:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="favicon.gif" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
```

3) Another thing could be the problem that **chrome can't display** favicons, **if it's local** (not uploaded to a webserver).

4) Try to rename it from `favicon.{whatever}` to `{yourfaviconname}.{whatever}` but I would suggest you to still have the normal favicon. This has solved my issue on IE.

5) Found another solution for this which works great! I simply added my favicon as Base64 Encoded Image directly inside the  tag like this:

```
<link href="data:image/x-icon;base64,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" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Used this page here for this: http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Answer (score 0):

On Local Host I was having this problem
So I changed the url

**from**

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/images/system/favicon.ico">
```

**to**

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../static/images/system/favicon.ico">
```

**Notice the double fullstops before the href**