# Favicon not showing up in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, favicon

I have a favicon icon which isn't showing up in Chrome (I'm not sure about other browsers as I only use Chrome) but the strange thing is if I type the path to the icon in the URL bar it shows up!

Why doesn't the icon appear?

Comment: We would give ideas, but that would be repeating the ways you can add a favicon. What have you done so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754613/favicon-wont-show-up-in-chrome-but-show-up-in-other-browsers-like-ie-firefox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705906/favicon-is-not-showing-on-chrome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780402/html-favicon-wont-show-on-google-chrome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711648/why-wont-my-sites-icon-show-up-in-google-chrome ... take your pick.

Comment: For me it was kind of cache issue. In inspector window I found the (href) url of the icon, right clicked and "open in new tab". After that it started displaying the favicon as well

Comment: An interesting page for checking (and creating) favicons: https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker

Comment: Most of time it happens, just close the inspector window of your browser and your favicon icon will show up.

Comment: TIP (might help some people coming here): Try hard refreshing with Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 307, accepted):

### Cache

Clear your cache. http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95582 And test another browser.

Some where able to get an updated favicon by adding an URL parameter: `?v=1` after the link href which changes the resource link and therefore loads the favicon without cache (thanks @Stanislav).

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico?v=2"  />
```

### Favicon Usage

How did you import the favicon? How you should add it.

**Normal favicon:**

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

**PNG/GIF favicon:**

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="favicon.gif" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
```

in the `<head>` Tag.

### Chrome local problem

Another thing could be the problem that **chrome can't display** favicons, **if it's local** (not uploaded to a webserver). Only if the file/icon would be in the downloads directory chrome is allowed to load this data - more information about this can be found here: [local (file://) website favicon works in Firefox, not in Chrome or Safari- why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221292/local-file-website-favicon-works-in-firefox-not-in-chrome-or-safari-why/30037071#30037071)

### Renaming

Try to rename it from `favicon.{whatever}` to `{yourfaviconname}.{whatever}` but I would suggest you to still have the normal favicon. This has solved my issue on IE.

### Base64 approach

Found another solution for this which works great! I simply added my favicon as Base64 Encoded Image directly inside the  tag like this:

```
<link href="data:image/x-icon;base64,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" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Used this page here for this: http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

### Generate favicons

I can really suggest you this page: http://www.favicon-generator.org/ to create all types of favicons you need.

Comment: Hi, nope. Didn't work. Well it did when I first accessed my website and after that it no longer shows. I'm using '.ico' format.

Comment: You uploaded it to a websever?

Comment: I could not make it work with ico file in Chrome (FireFox is fine), but it works with png file.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Closing and reopening tab in Chromium worked for me!

Comment: Also the link needs to be in the header and not in the body of an html webpage. Firefox wont have issues loading it, but chrome wont (since it should not). Also a nice way to force refresh is to use ?v=1 at the end of the file location. `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico?v=2" type="image/x-icon" />`

Comment: Great answer. I would make sure you use both `link rel = icon` and `link rel=shortcut icon`.

Comment: @DominikAngerer  I am not sure what `Another thing could be the problem that chrome can't display favicons, if it's local (not uploaded to a webserver).` this is supposed to mean. I have displayed favicon.ico while serving pages from files locally using exactly the same way as you suggested for `.ico` in your answer.

Comment: The Base64 solution works on my Chrome on local dev. Thanks.

Comment: Only solution works for me is Base64.

Comment: None of these solutions work for me.  Firefox displays it fine.  No others do.  It's running locally but in docker so it is using a webserver (nginx).   Even the base64 solution does nothing in chrome.

Comment: Point 6 was really helpful. It worked for me.

Comment: @Stanislav thanks. Your solution should be as an answer of this question. It was the only one what worked for me ;-)

Comment: None works. What works for me is I just ditch the .ICO format and go with PNG. It works all the time. ICO winblows format sucks.

Comment: Adding ?v=2 worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: base64 make problem in google mobile SERP, it is not visible

Comment: Weird that clearing cache doesn't fix it but changing the url does fix it...

Answer (score 72):

I read a bunch of different entries till I finally found a solution that worked for my scenario (ASP.NET MVC4 project).

Instead of using the filename **favicon.ico** for my icon, I renamed it to something else, ie **myIcon.ico**.  Then I just used exactly what Domi posted:

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="myIcon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

And this worked!

It's not a caching issue because I tested this with Fiddler - a request for favicon never occurred, even if I cleared my cache "From the beginning of time".  I believe it's just some odd bug with chrome?

Comment: Yeah, worked for me also.  Had to name it something other than favicon.ico and change the HTML link.

Comment: Can anyone share a fiddler or something similar?

Comment: renaming it solved the issue for me! thanks so much for this.

Comment: I also found renaming the image (instead of just `favicon.ico`, renamed it as `logo.ico`) finally works for me (running a flask server). how strange!

Answer (score 12):

Upload your `favicon.ico` to the root directory of your website and that should work with Chrome. Some browsers disregard the meta tag and just use `/favicon.ico`

Go figure?.....

Comment: This way not working on IE as well, have to add the link to make it works

Comment: I tried that, it worked with Firefox and not with Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

I also experienced the same thing. I found out that my favicon.ico had not been processed as a legitimate shortcut icon. I understand that favicons must be scaled to 16x16 and follow the Microsoft Icon format.

Comment: for me i was calling other .php files with full html sytax... like head body etc... into my file... removing the sytax from the source files fixed it for me