# How to add a font awesome icon to title

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome, title

So I was wondering if there was a way to have a font awesome icon beside your title like this[image: Font awesome example] I want to use the `fa fa-pencil`icon. This is my code in my head:

```
<head>
  <title><link type="fa fa-pencil" href="fa fa-pencil">Blogger</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

All what shows up in my title is:

```
<link type="fa fa-pencil" href="fa fa-pencil">Blogger
```

In my gem file, I have added gem `"font-awesome-rails"` and ran bundle install.
Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a way to add the pencil icon to the title? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156240/use-font-awesome-icon-as-favicon

Comment: @SubashYes, but the problem is that the icon is not showing up.

Comment: Generate as `.ico` format and use like this `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.ico"/>`

Comment: How to generate as `.ico` format? Sorry, I don't get what you mean by that

Comment: https://paulferrett.com/fontawesome-favicon/ use this and you will get `favicon-pencil.ico` file. And use that as favicon `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.ico"/>`

Comment: @Subash I have this: `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-pencil.ico"/>` and it still show `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-pencil.ico"/>` in my title. Is there something I should change?

Comment: Check your icon path in `href`. And Check whether you have included the `favicon.ico` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162177/discussion-between-subash-and-iirosie1).