# Favicon is not displaying

Tags: html

I can't find the problem, my favicon is not working.

HTML

```
<head>
    <title>SuomiFTB</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/text.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://suomiservut.arkku.net/Finland-icon.ico">
</head>
```

Comment: restart your server, the url is working

Comment: Your syntax on the page is full of errors: `<body bgcolor="gray </body> <body> <head>`. Cause of that the browser places the `<link rel="shortcut icon" ` inside of the `body` which might be the reason why it is not displayed.

Comment: you favicon is working on firefox, ie its not working in chrome this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375592/favicon-not-showing-up-in-google-chrome

Comment: While you fixed on of the syntax errors, your `head` tag is still a child of `body` which is invalid and still results in my described problem. Before asking questions you should make sure that your page has a valid syntax. To check this you can e.g. use [W3C: Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsuomiservut.arkku.net%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=HTML5&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices).