# Favicon icon does not show in chrome

Tags: html

The link tag is:
`<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://otranscribe.com/favicon.png">`

it works for all browsers except chrome.

Comment: have you tried clearing the browser cache? also, is there any errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 1):

As said before it is probably your cache if not then the following might be of use, these anwser have been quoted from: [Favicon not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375592/favicon-not-showing-up-in-google-chrome) So you might want to check that link.

If clearing your browser did not work then it might be the way how you included it

How you should add it: 
Normal favicon:

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

PNG/GIF favicon:

`<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="favicon.gif" />`
`<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />`

Or are you looking at your site locally? because google chrome can't display favicons if they are not uploaded to a webserver, this might be your problem.

If you use [Favicon Generator](http://www.favicon-generator.org/) you can create all types of favicons you need if these options did not work I suggest checking the link where I quoted the anwesers from I hope this helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Hmm I suppose this is true, well in this case I shall include some parts thanks for telling me.

Comment: Flag answers as "duplicate", this will work fine for "stackoverflow" internal links. And finally, you will recieve some badges for flagging "duplicates". Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for telling me! I am a new user indeed so just trying to help

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you get data from Cache. Try deleting cache and then try again.
Most probably it is due to that.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+F5 or else Clear your website cache and reload the page. It will work fine, and your code is correct.

**P.S. Try in Incognito Mode and check**

[html](/questions/tagged/html) [fav-icon](/questions/tagged/fav-icon) [chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome)