# favicon not loaded after firebase deployment

Tags: firebase

Hi is there any reason why favicon.ico is not loaded in deployed site ?

I have in my index.html head

```
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
```

When loading the index.html from my public dir the icon loads fine.

However after 'firebase deploy' the icon does not load.

Any help ?

Comment: Check in your browser's network tab, whether it is requesting the favicon. Favicons don't immediately load.

Comment: no it does not appear in the network tab but it does show in the elements tab

Comment: If it doesn't show in the network tab, the browser is not requesting it.

Comment: ok, but it does request and show it in the non deployed version ... ?

Comment: also another thing I see, in the 'elements' tab I see <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico"> ==$0 ... if I go the the console and type console.log($0) I get"<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico"> ... this ==$0 appear next to body in the local (not deployed) version

Comment: It is up to the browser to determine when it wants to show a favicon. Have a look at one of the many questions about that, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375592/favicon-not-showing-up-in-google-chrome, https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/7759/how-long-does-it-take-for-a-custom-favicon-to-show-up-on-your-site.html

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. I now see the browser actually fails loading the file. If I use for example: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/myicon.ico?cb=1" type="image/x-icon" /> then (every time I increase the cb value, deploy and reload) I get in the network tab: 404 not found ! Any help ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For some reason having the icon in a sub dir failed. Moving it to the root directory solved this issue.

Answer (score 11):

The issue occurs because your browser cached the old icon and still displays it. Hard reload your webpage to fix, in Chrome `cmd+shift+R #mac OR ctrl+shift+R # windows/Linux`

Answer (score 1):

You may try below:

Your icon should be inside the public folder:

```
yourproject_name/public/favicon.ico
```

and use this in your index.html file

```
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is just wait for a while, or using *another web browser*.
I just had the same thing with Chrome, but the icon is displayed well on Firefox or Brave.
*Happy coding!*

Comment: Yup, Chrome was the culprit. Tried it in Safari and it showed instantly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was about to the domain system.

But solution is simple.

MacOS -> CMD + SHIFT + R

Windows -> CTRL + SHIFT + R