# fav icon not showing in chrome browser

Tags: php, html, favicon, ico

my website showing fav icon in Firefox but not showing up in chrome browser, in chrome browser the index page is showing but the other pages not showing up , please help me to fix this.

my website : http://www.tempfisher.com/

other page where fav icon not showing : http://www.tempfisher.com/template/zara-photography

i used the following code : `

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.tempfisher.com/fav.png" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.tempfisher.com/fav.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`
```

Comment: Hmmm... 404 on http://www.tempfisher.com/favicon.ico

Comment: i done this website using codeigniter, so its may be the reason ----(framework)

Comment: [link](http://www.tempfisher.com/fav.png) this is the url

Comment: The icon looks fine now. Did you fix the issue?

Comment: no, its still not showing except index page

Comment: It's working for me in Chrome. It's probably not showing for you because of caching. Give it some time or clear your cache.

Comment: Please refer to this Url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375592/favicon-not-showing-up-in-google-chrome