# Wordpress favicon not showing on post pages

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes, favicon

My favicon is only showing on the homepage, not on post pages? I have tried clearing my cache, but it's still not showing?

Anyone know how to help? I have set up my favicon in wordpress customizer: site identity

**[Site Link](http://www.oihanevalbuenaredondo.be)**

Comment: Hello... It's not showing in homepage also...

Comment: It's appearing on all pages for me in `Firefox` but not in `Chrome`

Comment: Yes right... It' s showing in Firefox

Comment: This post may help you: [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375592/favicon-not-showing-up-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your favicon has been added in a non-standard way. I can see it in Internet Explorer, but not Chrome. Viewing the page source (Ctrl-U) shows there are incomplete favicon meta fields. For example

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://oihanevalbuenaredondo.be/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Roosje-website-32x32-trans.png" sizes="32x32" />
```

is missing the definition `type="image/png"`. For more info you can check Bhumi Patel's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375592/favicon-not-showing-up-in-google-chrome).

Try the [All In One Favicon](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-favicon/) plugin, it should solve the issue.

Comment: I have already tried the all in one favicon, but it doesnt work :s I will try the type thing that you said right now, see if that works

Comment: I have put `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://s3.postimg.org/mnqumfy8z/Roosje_website_32x32_trans.png" />` inside the `<head>` it's still not showing up on all the pages

Comment: I have also tried the base64, not working either :s, i don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I think I know what's wrong, I had a plugin to paste extra html in the head section but it's not actually printing it in the head, it's in the body, that's the problem I guess

Comment: @Oihane Two alternative ways are to 1. put a favicon.ico file in your web root, or 2. edit your theme header directly (see Bhumi Patel's link). This latter one would ideally by done in theme configuration, or making a child theme.

Comment: @Oihane Also, 3. if a plugin doesn't work as intended, the plugin's developer would usually like to know about this and might solve it for you quite quickly :) Check out their Support tab on WordPress.org plugin page, and if no one has reported the same issue, open a new one.