# favicon icon in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem with my favicon icons, they are in public folder inside img folder and html looks like this:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="img/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="img/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="img/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="img/manifest.json">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="img/browserconfig.xml">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png">
```

I am 100% sure that the href is correct because if I copy it it shows me the image, however the icon is not displayed in the tab. What can I do about it?

Comment: Try it in different browsers. Also clear browser cache.

Comment: so this is funny on other browsers it works fine however on google chrome it doesn't i tried to clear cache in the settings is there any other way to try and clear it

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375592/favicon-not-showing-up-in-google-chrome

Comment: First, you'll want absolute URLs, because on `foo/bar` your `img/apple-touch-icon.png` will become `foo/img/apple-touch-icon.png` and cause a 404. The best way to do this is via Laravel's `url()` helper, i.e. `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="{{ url('img/apple-touch-icon.png') }}">
`

Comment: funny thing is it doesn't work on any device with google chrome

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `?version=1` to href. Google Chrome caches favicons very hard.

Comment: where does it go exactly after ico?

Comment: img/favicon.ico?version=1

Comment: still the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{{URL::asset('img/favicon-16x16.png')}}">
```