# How to set/link favicon in yield laravel on chrome?

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, php-7, laravel-blade

I want to put my link icon in yield and it doesn't work,

If I put on section it work smoothly. I don't want to put it in every page.

Here is my code

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<title>@yield('title')</title>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no' name='viewport' />
<!--     Fonts and icons     -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700,200" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="72x72" href="{{{ asset('assets/img/ficon.png') }}}">

<!-- CSS Files -->
<link href="./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="./assets/css/now-ui-kit.css?v=1.1.0" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- CSS Just for demo purpose, don't include it in your project -->
<link href="./assets/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Update :: I was open in firefox it works but can't display on chrome, also I was update my chrome but still not working...

Comment: You have {{{ }}} for a start, it's just {{ }}

Comment: @Option You can see up there my code's use {{{ }}}

Comment: What? if its in a blade it should be: `href="{{ asset('assets/img/ficon.png') }}`

Comment: Pretty sure you don't need asset anyway.. should just be: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/img/ficon.png" type="image/x-icon" />`

Comment: You need to convert the .png to a .ico too

Comment: @Option it still doesn work ,, please help me,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the size, your png might be too big.

```
 //resize the image using a photo editing software to either 144x144,114x114 or  72x72 
 //then specify the size like below

 <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="114x114" href="{{{ asset('assets/img/ficon.png') }}}">
```

or try this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="114x114" href="assets/img/ficon.png">
```

you can also try this solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375592/favicon-not-showing-up-in-google-chrome) to fix the chrome issue

Comment: thank you, It works but only in mozila, but if I open in chrome it can't displayed are you know how to fix it?

Comment: still can't displayed, I really stuck with this... I've trying to resize , convert to base64 , del chache chrome , update chrome , convert into ico , calling with php include.. but chrome didn't response this.. Any another idea??

Comment: it's work when I put one of code's I've tried into **section** file, and all would mess on **yield** file...

Comment: nah.... I've solve my mistake. it's wrong if you moved the public folder to out of root folder in laravel, so ... don't try to pull out the public folder or file include them out, just run 'php artisan serve' and youre project would run at localhost:8000 without public directory....  thanks for youre update answer @Al3x Osaz