# Favicon issue in Google Chrome

Tags: html, wordpress, image, cross-browser, favicon

In my wordpress site favicon showing all browsers except google chrome would give direct URL link also but not working on chrome, i used the code like this

```
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/favicon.ico"  type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: Please have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375592/favicon-not-showing-up-in-google-chrome

Comment: Are you sure you are not loading the website from cache? press Crtl+F5 in chrome to reload your site without using cache and check it again.

Comment: thanks mahdi, i clear the cache and tried but still not working, can u pls check the website in your browser https://www.cloudnippon.com/

Comment: try placing favicon in root folder not under theme..root folder means, the folder which contains wp-content, wp-admin etc and call it as href="<?php echo home_url().'/favicon.ico';?>"

Comment: Hi charan, in home page only favicon showing, but in other pages not showing

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has its own Site Icon functionality.

Try this:

- Go to `wp-admin` of your website.
- In the left sidebar, Appearance --> Customize.
- Customize will open in the left sidebar.
- Go to the 1st option - 'Site Identity'
- Set your Site Icon.

Now check your website again on Chrome.

> Edit

Link your favicon directly in your header.

- Upload your favicon.png in your `public_html` section via FTP or CPanel File Manager.
- In your child theme, copy `header.php` from your main theme.
- In the `<head></head>` section, add this code:

  `<link rel="icon" href="YOURSITEURL/favicon.png">`

Include the `http://` / `https://` in `YOURSITEURL`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Hamza, I tried that method also but won't work any other method is there

Comment: Hi hamza i will changed header.php in wp-admin it shows the favicon only on  home page, other pages not showed

Answer (score 0):

I checked your site source and found there is issue that icons tag shows under body tag.

icon tag should be in head tag

Comment: thanks atul, i cross checked but meta tag should be header tag only

Comment: i mean your link icon tag, i edited my post also, It's works in my chrome