# Favicon in Google Chrome won't show

Tags: google-chrome, favicon

My favicon won't show in Google Chrome. It shows on my localhost, but not on the server. Works in other browsers. It doesn't show up when others visit the page nor in incognito mode. No errors, and the url is correct (I can see it if i go to the url). Nothing weird in the head aswell.

Here's the code:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/favicon.png"/>
```

Here's the thing i've already tried after searching for an answer:

- Cleared cache
- Set version `?v=2` on url
- Set reference `?r=31241` on url
- Renamed image
- Deleted image and uploaded the image again
- Restared Chrome
- Updated Chrome
- Added `type="image/png"`
- Convert image to base64 encoded

Comment: Is that type correct? I though it needed to be  type="image/ico", see [favico info](https://perishablepress.com/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-favicons/)

Comment: @lloyd A favicon can be in the format png aswell! It also says so in the link you sent

Comment: [base64 encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375592/favicon-not-showing-up-in-google-chrome/16375622#16375622)?

Comment: @lloyd Yeah that's not working aswell

Comment: How large is this image. Can you use a compressed format like jpg?

Comment: @lloyd 32x32 as it should be. Not working as jpeg nor ico