# Favicon does not appear

Tags: html, favicon

I'm trying to add a favicon in HTML, I have seen a video about it and this code works perfectly in the video:

```
<html>
  <header>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
  </header>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, it does not work in my case:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

You can get the files I'm using from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QeWBTorbrURTpmJvHU6UoWQSBdz1tQco/view?usp=sharing) in case you need them (it includes the icon)

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375592/favicon-not-showing-up-in-google-chrome

Comment: Ok, so I have checked it, I put ```<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />``` and ```<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />```inside the header, I have cleaned the cache and nothing. I have the same issue in other browsers as well (I have tried with Edge and IE) and there's no icon in any of them... How weird!

Comment: Sorry, I have no other suggestions, I have had favicon problems before but they are usually related to cache. Good luck, hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: Is `images` on the document root? If so, and your file `text.html` is within a subfolder, you may be referencing it incorrectly. Try having `href="/images/favicon.ico"`

Comment: Yes, of course. I tried it with a ```<img>``` in the body and the icon showed up.

Comment: Could you check your console and see if you are getting any error? perhaps a `404`?

Comment: Check this: https://i.imgur.com/y07hvKR.png (```<link>``` doesn't even appear inside the header on the Chrome Inspect Tool) and I don't see any error in the console.

Comment: Ooops sorry, ```<head>``` has confused me. Yes, it does appear: https://i.imgur.com/68JHXGW.png

Comment: Have you tried serving the html? Like with node, apache, nginex, or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work, because in your code you wrote `<header>` instead of `<head>` and `</header>` instead of `</head>`.

It should be like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, finally! This answer has worked. @Tijani already told me that it should be inside ```<head>``` but still the icon did not show up with his/her code. Yours works well, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this by adding the icon like so

```
<link type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

PS:the favicon.ico should be in the root of your project directory :)

Comment: Nope, I don't understand what's going on. I can't even see it inside the header on the Chrome Inspect Tool: https://i.imgur.com/y07hvKR.png

Comment: Ooops sorry, ```<head>``` has confused me. Yes, it does appear: https://i.imgur.com/68JHXGW.png

Comment: Glad to know Adrian

Comment: I mean, it does appear on the Chrome Inspect Tool but the icon still does not show up in the tab.

Comment: Oh, it should be in the <head></head > tag like so :
<head>
<link type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>

The relod with ctrl + shift r

Comment: Nope... https://i.imgur.com/MKU2JOc.png. Really, this is so weird.

Comment: can I see your directory structure

Comment: Yes, I have it inside a folder named "test" in the desktop and this is the structure: https://i.imgur.com/QCOZSbS.png also, a file ```debug.log``` is created each time I open the html file through Chrome and it contains all this: https://i.imgur.com/kIZJfVd.png. I think these lines are telling us that there's an error or something when trying to load the icon.

Comment: The  favicon.ico should be in the root of the directory

Comment: Omg, that didn't work either. Maybe my computer is broken or something haha. See: https://i.imgur.com/MbGcy3w.png

Do you think the icon might be the issue maybe? Should I try with another one?

Comment: Ok, the issue was your code. Snuwerd's one has worked for me! Thanks for the help!! :)