# Django static files not found when I try to specify favicon

Tags: python, django, image, static, favicon

I'm developing my first Django website.

I have an issue with static files.
In my homepage I linked my logo with this code.

```
<img class="d-block mx-auto mb-4" src="{% static 'mysite/images/logo.png' %}" alt="" width="300" height="225">
```

It was perfectly ok.

When I tried to change my favicon and tried to link another .png file from the static folder, it can't find the favicon png image.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static '/mysite/images/logo.png' %}" >
```

I don't know why it doesn't detect the favicon while getting the logo.

My settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

If I try to link another pictures It can't find. Only my logo.png is available.

[image: My project folder structure]

Comment: Apparently the image is found, otherwise you wouldn't been able to see it first. The problem may be for the favicon itself (not about Django). Have you tried the answers of this post for the favicon? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375592/favicon-not-showing-up-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

add **`STATICFILES_DIRS`** in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') <----- comment this line
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static'] <----- add this line
```